# Transport Protocols Firebase Realtime Database Uses

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

There are many data transport mechanisms such as Websockets, Server Sent Events as HTML5 Transports as well as old transports like Forever frame and ajax long polling. Which transport does firebase uses?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase uses a websocket over HTTPS.

Comment: If a browser doesn't support WebSockets how is the fallback mechanism?

Comment: It uses long polling.

Comment: How does firebase handles multiple parallel connections when long polling is been used?